# Error that runs mistakenly the previous codes when Actually want to run the current code in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I've got problem with my NetBeans app, once I click on the run button, it runs the previous program
I coded. Like in the image, I ran the program (Which is  PasswordGUI) and it indescribably ran the previous code (Which was Ourproject)

.. So, I'm stuck in here and need help

best wishes

I tried to search if my project in the app have kind of untidy which may this problem the untidiness
of my projects..

Comment: To be certain that you run the desired project, first select it in the _Projects_ panel (so that the background color for that node changes, to denote selection), then right click the mouse to open the context menu for that project, and then select the **Run** menu entry. If that doesn't resolve the issue you will need to update your question with more details, and evidence of the problem.

Comment: It resolved the issue but.However, when I click on run button in the upper panel it runs the previous one..So do I have to suspend the previous project?